# Scan for a new record in a database

Tags: c#, sql

I have a program in C# that works like this with a database:

```
while(record found)
{
   SPEAKS RECORD OUT TO SPEAKER
   DELETES RECORD
}
```

It works fine until it runs out of Records.

What I want is to keep scanning even after there are no records found in the database. 
When a record appears it should do the logic. How do I refresh the database so it scans for the new record?

Any ideas?

Comment: You need to implement some sort of polling solution, or write a trigger in your database that can execute external code so that you can handle record insertions.

Comment: What do you mean by "refresh the database"?

Answer (score 4):

You'll probably want to wait some time before checking for new records. So iterate forever and check for a new record. If you have one, proceed as usual. If you have no records, wait (for instance 2 seconds) and try again

```
while(true){
    if(record found){
        // SPEAKS RECORD OUT TO SPEAKER
        // DELETES RECORD
    }else{
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000); // sleep two seconds
    }
}
```

If you don't wait between requests then you'll run into problems for continuously asking for new records.

Another issue is the "iterate forever" part. Usually, what you do is not iterate forever, but limit the number of continuous attempts you make to read a new record:

```
int attempts = 0;
while(attempts < 3){
    attempt++;
    if(record found){
        // SPEAKS RECORD OUT TO SPEAKER
        // DELETES RECORD
        attempts=0; // reset attempts counter
    }else{
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000); // sleep two seconds
    }
}
```

So your program won't be trying forever.

Comment: actually i am using a service, so I want it to run forever.

Comment: @Apollo then you can go with the `while(true)`. Another option is to have your service wait for a signal that a new record is available.

Answer (score 2):

From your pseudo code it looks like you ran an ADO command that did a SELECT. You will iterate over these results as they were when the command ran. It isn't a volatile data structure.

So you'd run the SELECT command again to see if any new records have appeared since the last time you ran SELECT.